# Google Maps API error location manager

Tags: java, google-maps, maps

I started playing around today with the google maps API for the first time but I already got an error and I have no idea how to fix it.

I have no idea why locationManager is giving this error: `cannot resolve symbol 'locationManager'`

Thanks in advance,

For the full code go to: http://pastebin.com/7Cy8GYyF

Here is the part of the code:

```
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(52.279413, 5.194046)).title("l"));

    // Enable MyLocation layer of Google Map
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    //get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    //Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLoacation(provider);

    //set map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


    //get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    //get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    //create a latlng object for current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //show the current location in Google Map
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    //zoom in the google map
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is case -sensitive . You have declared variable as 'locationmanager ' and are trying to access it as 'locationManager'. Notice case of 'M'.

Comment: when i run it now i get another error. Could you maby tell me what it says: